# Updating to 20.04 broke s2disk hibernate

Tags: 20.04, hibernate

I have s2disk hibernation on 19.10.  But now when I `sudo s2disk` I see:

1. The screen briefly flashes to dark.
2. There are lines about calculating space
3. It flashes dark again

Then I am immediately kicked back to the login screen.

What should I do to figure out what's going on?

### Update

And `sudo pm-hibernate` is even worse.  It just turns off the machine and saves nothing.  Next time I booted up, I lost all my work.

Comment: f there are any clues in /var/log/syslog or jouralctl -x, then please file a bug report. It will be low priority (hibernation is explicitly not supported for several reasons) but some developers like to poke at the problem.

Comment: Oh goodness, I didn't realize hibernation was unsupported!  This is crucial for laptop usage.

Comment: Hibernation does work for many users under most circumstances. However, it's deliberately disabled and hidden because the Ubuntu developers cannot be sure that it will work for all new users (with healthy equipment) under most common circumstances. We don't want new users to lose data. This is, fundamentally, a kernel-and-hardware-manufacturer problem; all distros share the same pain, some handle it differently. Your bug seems like a *regression*: Something stopped working, and if a kernel developer can get enough data to figure out the commit that caused the problem, they can revert it.

Comment: Also do you have enough swap?

Comment: Always had enough swap before, and don't expect 20.04 would have changed that.

Comment: I'm not seeing any output from `grep s2disk /var/log/syslog`

Comment: My swap is 2x the size of my RAM

Answer (score 1):

There is a  kernel bug that causes such behavior 
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206713
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-5.4/+bug/1864930